# How does redirect after post works?

Tags: php, redirect-after-post

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Back button re-submit form data ($_POST)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146431/back-button-re-submit-form-data-post)

some guys suggest me rather then editing the question put it as new question that's why i am doing so...

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['username']) && ($_POST['password'])) 
{

                $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
                if(!$con)
                {
                die('Could Not Connect:'.mysql_error());
                } 

                mysql_select_db("tcs",$con);

                $usr=$_POST["username"];                 //pick username from login page
                $pwd=hash('sha1',$_POST['password']);    //pick password from login page and use hash algorithm to encrypt it

                $query="select * from employee where Username='$usr' and Password='$pwd'";  //serch that single row in which both r found
                $result=mysql_query($query,$con);


                    if ($result) 
                    {

                                $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);

                        if (($row["Username"]==$usr) && ($row["Password"]==$pwd))
                        {

                                $_SESSION['employee']['id']=$row['User Id'];
                                $_SESSION['employee']['username']=$row['Username'];
                        }       
                        else
                        {
                                echo "Login Not Successfull";
                        }
                    }   
}

else
{
echo 'Error! Username & Password were not sent!';
}

$_SESSION['user_authenticated'] = true;

?>

<html>
<body bgcolor="black">


<?php 
if($_SESSION['user_authenticated']) 
{


                                echo "<font color=red>"."<h3 align=center>"."Welcome ".$_SESSION['employee']['username']."</h3>"."</font>";
                                echo "<br />"."<a href='upload_file.php'>"."<font color='white'>"."<h4>"."Up-Load Files"."</h4>"."<font>"."</a>";
                                echo "<br />"."<br />"."<a href='list_files.php'>"."<font color='white'>"."<h4>"."List All Up-Loaded Files"."</h4>"."<font>"."</a>";

}



?>

</font>
<a  href="logout_file.php"><font color="white"><h3 align="right">Sign Out</h3></font></a>
<font color="white">

</body>
</html>
```

Ok fine now i am getting the point.But there is one more problem.Suppose i am on signin-action page which have a link of sign out.When i click on sign out button i am re-directed to sign in page.ok no problem but again if i press back button again i am asked to resend the data(even after sign out) and again i am on sign-in-action page why so. It is wrong yar..What to do this.For all other pages like if i click on sign out button from upload 
button->redirected to sign-in and if i press back button it shows u are signed out. I don't know how to check session variable exit for signinaction

as felix sir told me to check this http://www.thefutureoftheweb.com/blog/get-redirect-after-post

but really i am not getting what this guy is saying.I am sorry i am not so techanical becuase i am a begineer I know what problem i am facing...

as far as i know

```
    if (count($_POST)) {             //checking how many time data is being resend.
        // process the POST data
   add_comment($_POST);        //what this function do i dont know 

   // redirect to the same page without the POST data
header("Location: ".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);  //i think it is like  
                                //refreshing without get input again from allpication form
        die;
    }
```

Please, explain it, especially what is this `$_server(;PHP_SELF)`

Comment: you might want to revise the title of your post...

Comment: [Here is the possible solution to your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146431/back-button-re-submit-form-data-post). Thanks

Comment: The title of this question is FAR too long. It should be a brief outline of the question, not the whole question. I imagine if there was a way to put `code` in the title it could all have been there. ;-D

Comment: "Ok fine now i am getting the point.But there is one more problem.Suppose".... Could you remove the previous code block?  I can't see how it's relevant.  Can you focus on just the problem without the other material?

Comment: (1) Please don't comment on your own question.  You own the question, you can fix it.  (2) Did you just repeat the question as a comment?  Why?  (3) If you did not repeat the question as a comment, why not just fix the question?  Please delete the two comments and fix the question.

Comment: thanks really it was nice explaination...Problem solved

Answer (score 0):

About `$_SERVER` - see [this](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).