# Skip location from being pushed to the browser navigation history stack

Tags: browser, redirect, browser-history

Assuming the following scenario:

- User is on *product list* page
- Clicks a product and is redirected to the *product detail* page
- Clicks on *purchase* button
- `POST /products/1/purchase/` is executed and redirects back to *product detail* page
- User clicks *back* button
- `POST /products/1/purchase/` is executed again (**FAIL!** it should have been redirected to *product list* page)

How would you solve the *back* button problem?
Is there any response code that forces the browser to skip the location from history stack?

Assuming I can implement my own *back* button, how would you implement it?

- Manually tracking the history, client-side
- Manually tracking the history, server-side
- Setting checkpoints and redirecting back to the checkpoint in case of existence

Answer (score 0):

See:

[Back button re-submit form data ($_POST)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146431/back-button-re-submit-form-data-post)