# IE back button empty fields

Tags: internet-explorer

I have a form which I submit.
When I'm on the submitted page and I press
the back button in Internet Explorer, I still 
see the values I entered in the fields.

A colleague uses the same form, and when using the back button
he gets all fields empty.

Is there a setting in IE that I have to change?

I use IE v. 9
my colleague uses IE v. 8

Comment: what version(s) of IE are you (andd your colleague) using?

Comment: is the form using POST or GET method to submit the data?

Comment: have yout tried clearing your browser cache (a full cache will mean it won't have space to keep your form data)

Comment: cache has been cleared-doesn't work. It's POST DATA

Comment: POSTed forms should not retain the data when you go back. If you want this behaviour, GET is probably more appropriate. (it does depend on the context though; this topic may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146431/back-button-re-submit-form-data-post)