# Avoid browser's back button resubmitting a form in a Front Controller application

Tags: php, forms, browser, controller, back

This is my first PhP-MySQL project and my first (ever) question. Am trying to make a small portal and in order to learn the basics I am trying to use the front controller pattern as I am not confident using the Observer pattern at present.

The front controller basically looks something like below and calls the appropriate method of the correct class:

```
$controller =''; $action =''; $queryString ='';
parseURL($controller, $action, $queryString);
$objView = new View;
if ($controller == 'adminlogin' && $action == 'authenticate') {
    AdminLogin::getInstance()->authenticate();
} else if ($controller && $action) {
    SessionFactory::getSession();
    if (isset($_SESSION['userName'])) { // and some more validations
        callHook($controller, $action, $queryString);
    } else {
        $objView->assign('message', SESSION_INVALID);
        $objView->display('index');
    } 
} else {
    $objView->display('index');
}
```

The view is also simple:

```
public function assign ($variable, $value)
{
    $this->passArray[$variable] = $value;
}

public function display ($view)
{
    $mapper = ViewmapSingleton::getinstance();
    if (1 == preg_match("/\/|\.|\\\\/", $view)) {
        echo 'View name should not contain . / or \ ';
    }
    $template = $mapper->getViewPath($view);
    if (!$template || is_dir($template)) {
        echo 'The requested view file does not exist';
    } else {
        extract ($this->passArray);
        include_once($template);
    }
}
```

My Problem is the Browser's BACK button when submitting $_POST forms. I am trying to make an Admin page that shows article listings and allows pagination, bulk actions, and 'search articles by title / category' etc.

From what I have read on this (most useful) website, there exist two solutions to prevent the Browser's back button from re-submitting a form:

Solution 1. Pass the search parameters to the action (method) by appending them to the URL using Javascript on the Search button.

```
<input id="btn1" type="submit" onclick="SubmitForm('index.php?   controller=articles&action=showList&articleTitle='+document.getElementById('articleTitle').value)" value="Search" name="btn1"></input>
```

=> Not the best way because there could be many many parameters like article-category etc.

Solution 2. Do not pass the parameters and instead use $_POST data in the called method. Save everything in $_SESSION and then redirect using header() to a separate display method in the same class. Extract everything from $_SESSION in the display function and generate the view.

=>Not the best way because there can be many many parameters that will have to be stored in the Session and then extracted.

Is there a more elegant way to prevent the browser's back button re-submitting a form when using a front controller? I ask because when using the front controller pattern, $_GET may not be of much use especially where some bulk actions require DB changes and are of the type "Unpublish".

Please ignore my ignorance and help!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Other way you could do this is by using redirection.

Updated: refer this solution. 
[Back button re-submit form data ($_POST)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146431/back-button-re-submit-form-data-post?rq=1)

Comment: The reference discussion would not help much when all requests are directed to one single file (like in the front controller pattern)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!

First, unless GET is absolutely necessary always use POST for form submission. (see details below)

Your PHP code should the exclusively rely on $_POST to retrieve submitted data ($_GET would be probably empty, and $_REQUEST combines both $_GET and $_POST).

After your application receives the form data, and probably processed it, redirect the browser. Do not send an HTML response, but rather a 302 Moved directing the browser to the next page:

A really very basic example:

```
session_start();                                       // make sure a session is available
if (is_array($_POST) && array_key_exists('submitbutton_name', $_POST)) {
    // user has submitted the form
    $inputdata = $_POST;                               // retrieve input data
    $next_page_html = determine_next_page($inputdata); // process and construct next page
    $_SESSION['page_to_show'] = $next_page_html;       // keep the HTML response

    // redirect the browser to the very same location, but using GET
    header('Location: ' + $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    exit;
}

// the redirect will end up here
if (array_key_exists('page_to_show', $_SESSION)) {
    // we have a next page to show
    echo $_SESSION['next_page_to_show'];
    // don't forget to remove the session entry
    unset($_SESSION['next_page_to_show']);
}
else {
    // output the starting page, probably the form that the user should submit
}
```

HTH

Comment: Excellent! I am not fond of $_GET either and your solution works like a charm. Just one small thing:  header('Location: ' + $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);exit; was showing a blank page for some reason, however, it worked with a minor change =>$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; header("Location: $uri");exit;

Comment: Since this is my first post, I am not sure if I should write this as an independent response or as a comment.                                 Ernest, with less parameters in Admin, above will work OK. However, the front-end too uses a front controller pattern too and directs all requests to index.php which calls an appropriate method in an appropriate class. Two minor queries:                             (1) If I use the above method on the front-end as well, should I start the Session right at the start even if its is not necessary?

Comment: (2) When building a shopping cart type site the front-end could have huge number of parameters. Should $_GET be used in such cases or can $_POST handle that too? (3) $_GET does not put $controller='something'&$action='something' in the URL so can it even be used in a Front Controller that requires a controller and action name?

Comment: Generally, use POST when you're changing/uploading data, and GET when retrieving data. POST does not have limits as GET doeas which is limited in length (check RFC for that).

Comment: As your shopping cart requires a session anyway you can just go ahead and start it upfront, and use it to store the current redirection state. OTOH, you could redirect to something like a SmartURL which would actually be handled by your index.php. The SmartURL will be available in $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'].